# Uniqueness validation not applying when creating multiple associated objects through nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-forms

I have models and views per below.

What I'm finding is that when I try to create multiple devices at the same time with the same serial, no error is thrown and all are created. If I'm trying to create a device which has an existing serial, then I get the correct error.

How can I change the uniqueness validation so that I can't create two devices with the same serial at the same time?

**models/service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :device_attributes
  has_many :devices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :devices
end
```

**models/device.rb**

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :serial
  belongs_to :service
  validates :serial, uniqueness: true
end
```

**views/services/_service_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @service do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :devices do |d| %>
    <%= d.input :serial %>
    <%= d.link_to_remove "Remove Device" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Device", :devices %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: serialize the serial number requests to a single serial number service (and say that 5 times fast)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you provide example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: [Validate uniqueness of a child object in a nested form not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705508/validate-uniqueness-of-a-child-object-in-a-nested-form-not-working-correctly)

or this: http://www.freezzo.com/2012/06/14/validating-uniqueness-of-nested-model-on-create

or merge both exemples:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   validate :uniqueness_of_devices

   private 
      def uniqueness_of_devices
        ids = self.devices.map {|d| d.id}
        if ids.detect{|i| ids.count(i) > 1 } == 1
           errors.add(:devices, "some message")
        end
       end
end
```